# Problem on motion in a straight line

Tags: dynamical-systems, physics

Question: A particle starts from rest at a distance b(>a) from a fixed point O under the action of a force through a fixed point, the law of which at a distance x from O is
$F= \mu (1-a/x)$ towards O when $x>a$ but
$F= \mu(a^2/x^2 - a/x)$ away from O when $x<a$.
Show that the velocity of the particle will again vanish when $x= a^2/b$

I've taken the differential equations
$v dv/dx = -\mu(1-a/x)$, limit $v:0 \rightarrow V$, $x:b \rightarrow x$ and
$v dv/dx=\mu(a^2/x^2 - a/x)$, limit $v:V \rightarrow 0$, $x:a \rightarrow x$
After that I'm stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Formatting help is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be preferable to compare the work done on the particle along each path to $ \ x = a \ . $  For $ \ x > a \ , $ the force acts "to the left", so the change in kinetic energy of the particle is $$ \ -\int_b^a \mu·(1  - \frac{a}{x}) \ dx \ \ = \ \  \mu \ · \ (a \ln x \ - \ x)|_b^a \ \ . $$  When $ \ x < a \ , $ the force acts "to the right", so the change in KE along this path is $$ \ \int_X^a \mu·(\frac{a^2}{x^2}  - \frac{a}{x}) \ dx \ \ = \ \  \mu · \left( -\frac{a^2}{x}  - a \ln x \right)|_X^a \ \ , $$ where $ \ X < a \ $ is the starting point.  Since the particle is (momentarily) at rest at each end, these work integrals will be equal.

While you *could* solve the equation for $ \ X \ , $ you are just asked to "verify" that setting $ \ X \ = \ \frac{a^2}{b} \ $ makes the two amounts of work equal.

Comment: How do you solve the equation for X?

Comment: Once you have written out the terms from the anti-derivatives on both sides of the equation, certain terms will cancel; among what's left, matching the $ \ \frac{a^2}{X} \ $ term and the $ \ a \ln X \ $ term with terms from the first work integral will indicate the value for $ \ X \ . $  But you could also just insert the value for $ \ X \ $ from the problem statement.